# Passing instance with button_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Pretty new to Ruby on Rails and reached my first road block I can't seem to figure out after some researching.

On my view, I am generating a button for each instance of "Newbie"

I would like to send the 'zendeskid' of each to my controller "giveticket"

So far, I have:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="containertop"></div>
        <p><%= newby.name %></p>
        <%= button_to "Give Ticket!", {:controller => "giveticket",:action => "new", :newby.zendeskid => @newby.zendeskid} %>        
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

however, I am getting "undefined method `zendeskid' for :newby:Symbol"

Could someone please point me in the right direction - a bit stuck at the moment!  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send any parameters to the controller action you can just send it with the action name.

`Named routing is more preferable and recommended to use in rails`. So you can write as,.

```
<%= button_to "Give Ticket!", new_giveticket_path(zendeskid:  newby.zendeskid) %>
```

Comment: Thank you Sasidaran - I did not know this.I tried it out this way and I still got "undefined method `zendeskid' for nil:NilClass" - zendeskid is a property of Newbie so am unsure what I have done wrong?

Comment: Ahh,.. instead of `@newby.zendeskid` change it to `newby.zendeskid`, things will work,.. Updated the answer, kindly try as said above.

Comment: That works! Thank you so much :) Could you point me in the direction on how I can now in the giveticket controller - grab zendeskid? I haven't found a good reference.  Thanks again!

Comment: Any new attribute / parameter added in view can be got in the controller as 'params', so in your controller you can get as 'params[:zendeskid]',...